# Can you partially copy an instance of a struct to another of a different type in one statement?

Tags: c

With a partial copy I'd expect to set the matching fields with a copy, but leave the non-matching fields unset (i.e. retain their previous values).

It doesn't seem to happen. I'm curious why and if this is some undefined behavior?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define print_base(s) printf("%d %d\n", s.a, s.b)
#define print_extended(s) printf("%d %d %d\n", s.a, s.b, s.c)

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
} base;

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} extended;

int main()
{
    base s1 = {1,2};
    extended s2 = {0};
    extended s3 = {0};
    extended s4 = {4,5,6};
    extended s5 = {4,5,6};
    extended s6 = {7,8,9};
    base s7 = {0};

    print_extended(s2);
    s2 = *(extended*)&s1;
    print_extended(s2);

    print_extended(s3);
    memcpy(&s3, &s1, sizeof(s3));
    print_extended(s3);

    print_extended(s4);
    s4 = *(extended*)&s1;
    print_extended(s4);

    print_extended(s5);
    memcpy(&s5, &s1, sizeof(s5));
    print_extended(s5);

    /* lossy copy */
    print_base(s7);
    s7 = *(base*)&s6;
    print_base(s7);

    return 0;
}

/*
Actual  Expected
0 0 0   0 0 0
1 2 1   1 2 0
0 0 0   0 0 0
1 2 1   1 2 0
4 5 6   4 5 6
1 2 1   1 2 6
4 5 6   4 5 6
1 2 1   1 2 6
0 0     0 0
7 8     7 8
*/
```

Comment: Undefined behavior for accessing beyond the bounds of an object in `memcpy(&s3, &s1, sizeof(s3));` since `sizeof(s1)` is less than `sizeof(s3)`.

Comment: Is this 'struct' day or what?

Answer (score 0):

```
s2 = *(extended*)&s1;
```

This has undefined behaviour, the object at `&s1` is not of the correct type to be accessed through a pointer of type `extended*`.

```
memcpy(&s3, &s1, sizeof(s3));
```

This also has undefined behaviour, because you read `sizeof(extended)` bytes from an object that is only `sizeof(base)` bytes long.

If you think about it, it obviously won't work as you expect. When you copy an `extended` structure the compiler reads three words (i.e. `sizeof(extended)`) from the source, and copies those three words to the destination. It doesn't copy less than three words and leave the last word unchanged. You told it to read `sizeof(extended)` bytes from the address `&s1` so that's exactly what it does. And the last member gets set to a garbage value, because you read it from a memory location that isn't part of `s1` and contains some garbage value.

Why do you expect the compiler to copy `sizeof(base)` bytes if you tell it to copy `sizeof(extended)` bytes? If you don't want it to copy more bytes then don't tell it to copy more bytes!

Comment: I guess you'd want: memcpy(&s3, &s1, sizeof(base)); rather than: memcpy(&s3, &s1, sizeof(extended)); ... in order to only copy the first 2 fields.

Comment: Yes, of course. If you only want to copy the contents of `s1` then don't tell it to copy `s1` plus whatever happens to be after it in memory!

Answer (score 0):

when you copy from one memory location to another using pointer casts you are basically 'taking matters into your own hands'

These statements:

```
s2 = *(extended*)&s1;
s1 = *(base*)&s2;
```

Are equivalent to these:

```
memcpy(&s2, &s1, sizeof(extended));
memcpy(&s1, &s2, sizeof(base));
```

I think it is clear why copying from **base* source** to **extended* dest** will overwrite only part of the data and the other way around can have disastrous consequences (you have an out of bounds memory access and might overwrite important data).